# How to get an analyzed term from a TokenStream in Lucene.NET 4.8

Tags: c#, lucene, lucene.net

I am using the following lines of code to extract an analyzed term from a TokenStream in Lucene.NET 4.8 but getting runtime errors.

```
var analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(LuceneVersion.LUCENE_48);
TokenStream tokenStream = analyzer.TokenStream(null, new StringReader("myterm"));

tokenStream.Reset();
while (tokenStream.IncrementToken())
{
    var termAttr = tokenStream.GetAttribute<ITermAttribute>();
    var analyzedTerm = termAttr.Term;
}
tokenStream.End();
tokenStream.Dispose();
```

Exception thrown: **An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in Lucene.Net.dll** and **Additional information: this AttributeSource does not have the attribute 'ITermAttribute'**

I´ve used the same approach in other versions of Lucene.NET which works fine.

Lucene.NET 3.0.3

```
var analyser = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_30);
var tokenStream = analyzer.TokenStream(null, new StringReader("myterm"));

tokenStream.Reset();
while (tokenStream.IncrementToken())
{
    var termAttr = tokenStream.GetAttribute<ITermAttribute>();
    var analyzedTerm = termAttr.Term;
}
tokenStream.End();
tokenStream.Dispose();
```

Lucene.NET 2.9.4.1

```
var analyser = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_29);
var tokenStream = analyser.TokenStream(null, new StringReader("myterm"));

tokenStream.Reset();
while (tokenStream.IncrementToken())
{
    var termAttr = tokenStream.GetAttribute(typeof(TermAttribute));
    var analyzedTerm = termAttr.ToString();
}
tokenStream.End();
tokenStream.Close();
```

Anyone who has done this in Lucene.NET 4.8?

Comment: I haven't, but have you tried using `TermAttribute` instead of `ITermAttribute`?

Comment: Yes. The `TermAttribute` seems to be gone and there´s no longer a `GetAttribute` (like Lucene.NET 2) that takes a `Type` param in v4.8.

Comment: Okay, I believe you would want to use `CharTermAttribute` instead (or `ICharTermAttribute`). This would parallel the same replacement made in the java API in version 4.0.

Comment: Superb! Replacing `ITermAttribute`with `ICharTermAttribute`and do a `ToString()`on the `termAttr`, will extract the analyzed term. Clever looking at the corresponding Java API. Thank you!